# react native error, login

Tags: php, react-native, authentication, syntax-error

I'm trying to make an app that logs in to a website (my school schedule site) using the php of the website. I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvgPx.jpg) error/syntax, can anyone help me? I added my code below.

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        userEmail:'',
        userPassword:'',
    }
}

login = () => {
    const {userEmail,userPassword} = this.state;
    alert(userEmail);

    fetch('http://tref.cals.nl/roosters/infoweb/index.php',{
        method:'post',
        header:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
            user: userEmail,
            paswoord: userPassword,
        })

    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=>{
            alert(responseJson);
        })

    Keyboard.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: please modify your question by including your errorcode as scroll-able text below the code you're using, and not as image. Ctrl-F is our friend ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send and receive JSON data - but the mentioned web page uses normal HTML forms and responds with HTML (instead of JSON).

Try something like:

```
let formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("username", 'test')
formdata.append("paswoord", 'pw')

fetch('http://tref.cals.nl/roosters/infoweb/index.php', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formdata
})
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response); // prints the returned HTML
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

By the way: The error you experienced happens, because you tried to parse a JSON string, which fails, because it's HTML (which starts with the mentioned `<` token).